# SQL Server : Copy row and replace first column first char and multipley other column from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, set

I would like to copy a row in a same table and change the copied row's first cell number (like 1 to 9) and multiply values of other cells with a value from another table.

**Table1**:

```
uniqueID ID2 ID3 Number Number
-------------------------------
199000   1   2   20     20
```

**Table2**:

```
MultiplyN ID2 ID3
-----------------
5         1   2
```

After insert and set and multiply

**Table1**:

```
uniqueID ID2 ID3 Number Number
-------------------------------
199000   1   2    20     20
999000   1   2   100    100
```

Here is my procedure only to copy and change first letter but it does nothing.

What I'm doing wrong ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tableInsertUpdate]  
    (@kulcs nvarchar(50),
     @uzlev int,
     @uzlho int,
     @uzltip int,
     @uzlnev char,
     @belfarb int,
     @exparb int,
     @egyarb int,
     @arbjova int,
     @allvalt int,
     @anyagkolt int,
     @energkolt int,
     @elabe int,
     @kozvetitettszolg int,
     @igbevettagjell int,
     @igenybevettszolg int,
     @berkoltsjar int,
     @egyebszem int,
     @egyebraf int,
     @koltsterh int,
     @ecs int,
     @berlvhep int,
     @berlvheszk int,
     @mfee int,
     @koltscostcent int,
     @penzeredvh int,
     @penzeredkulso int,
     @arfegyenleg int,
     @rendkered int,
     @letszam int,
     @bérelt_munkaerő int,
     @bérelt_munkaerők int)
AS
    UPDATE uzlag_2006_copy
    SET kulcs = '9' + SUBSTRING (@kulcs, 1, len(kulcs) - 1)
    WHERE kulcs = @kulcs

    INSERT INTO uzlag_2006_copy (kulcs, uzlev, uzlho, uzltip, uzlnev, belfarb,
                                 exparb, egyarb, arbjova, allvalt, anyagkolt,
                                 energkolt, elabe, kozvetitettszolg, 
                                 igbevettagjell, igenybevettszolg,
                                 berkoltsjar, egyebszem, egyebraf,
                                 koltsterh, ecs, berlvhep, berlvheszk,
                                 mfee, koltscostcent, penzeredvh,
                                 penzeredkulso, arfegyenleg, rendkered,
                                 letszam, bérelt_munkaerő, bérelt_munkaerők)
    VALUES (@kulcs, @uzlev, @uzlho, @uzltip, @uzlnev, @belfarb, @exparb,
            @egyarb, @arbjova, @allvalt, @anyagkolt, @energkolt, @elabe,
            @kozvetitettszolg, @igbevettagjell, @igenybevettszolg,
            @berkoltsjar, @egyebszem, @egyebraf, @koltsterh, @ecs,
            @berlvhep, @berlvheszk, @mfee, @koltscostcent, @penzeredvh,
            @penzeredkulso, @arfegyenleg, @rendkered, @letszam,
            @bérelt_munkaerő, @bérelt_munkaerők)
```

Comment: I don't know what your explanation of the problem and sample data has to do with the code.  Nothing appears to match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
insert into table1 (uniqueID, ID2, ID3, Number1, Number2)
    select stuff(uniqueID, 1, 1, '9')
           t1.ID2, t1.ID3,
           Number1 * t2.MultiplyBy, t1.Number2 * MultiplyBy
    from table1 t1 join
         table2 t2
         on t1.id2 = t2.id2 and t1.id3 = t2.id3;  -- Are both keys needed?
```

Answer (score 0):

Ill made a solution:

temp table inserted from table1 and tabl2 with join converted first char and multiplied the numbers and insert back with new data to original table